# Contact Permission not removing from app

Tags: android, permissions, android-contacts

I am working on android application, in which I have removed Contact Permission from my application. But still it is showing in App Settings. Below is my list of permissions which I am declaring, how can I trace why still Contact Permission is showing in App settings of Mobile.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <!-- If c2dm permission is removed, parse starts working, else c2dm takes control -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.responder.murgency.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Comment: `android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"` is still there....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

As you see in this image .. GET_ACCOUNT is under the CONTATCS hence it shows contacts permission in your App settings.

for more [read here...](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en)